# Gridview image gallery from binary data images

Tags: asp.net, image, gallery

I have some images stored in varbinary fields. I want get them into a List object e.g List list

From here I can access each image byte array, e.g image.ImageData.

I need to bind them somehow as thumbnails to asp:gridview or something similar, is it possible with binary/byte[] images?

Answer (score 1):

I would try a slightly different approach.

Use an HTTPHandler to retrieve the images and bind the image src to the handler

Embed something like this in your gridview:

```
<img src="http://www.yoursite.com/imageHandler.ashx?id=4" />
```

See this StackOverflow answer for how to write the handler:
[Create PNG image with C# HttpHandler webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887985/create-png-image-with-c-httphandler-webservice)