# dynamic image control

Tags: asp.net, image, httphandler

I am getting dynamic image in form of byte array. and i want to show that in webpage, preferably ImageControl

I am aware of method of creating http handler and getting image stream. but I cant do that here as logic for same is performed somewhere else.

Could not get any suitable way to do this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I took middle approach.

I am having image object in code behind. For shwoing that in main web page.

I am adding that object in Cache with one random key (in my case GUID). Then I am generating URL such as ~/GetImage.ashx?id=[GUID]

When this URL is accessed an image from cache will be stored.

Note:

1. I am adding image to cache with self expiration set to absolute 2 mins. to ensure cache will be empty without manual intervention and there is enough time for other processing to happen.
2. Used Cache over Session for same reason mentioned in point 2, where i may have to manually remove it.

Of course I am still open for better solution.

Comment: What if the user takes more than 2 minutes to load the page? Mobile devices often 'pause' loading when you switch to a different app, which would cause the images to not be available when loading resumes.  [There are httpmodules for dynamic image processing](http://imageresizing.net), if that's what you're doing.

Comment: Mentioned httpmodule is resizing images already present. Here we were dealing with Image Object in memnory.
In application I recieve Image Object from processing and need to display same in Image Control. My current application does not allow to store image as file, so could no give path directly. If it would have been allowed I could directly give path and remove image after long duration. Keeping image is cache is expensive so I had to remove after definite interval. You could modify interval as per application need.

Comment: Actually, [the httpmodule](http://imageresizing.net) doesn't require the images to be physically present. You can implement a 2-method interface (IVirtualImageProvider) and pass it virtual files at whim. But to help you find the best solution, we need more details about where the images are coming from.

Answer (score 0):

You can still convert your byte array to a stream in your handler and send the bytes as normal. Here's a good post on how to do that: [Creating a byte array from a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221925/creating-a-byte-array-from-a-stream)

Comment: yes, this will convert byte array to image stream and may be in image object but how to show that in webpage and how to assign it to Image control as it takes on image url.

Comment: This process is well documented here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/887985/create-png-image-with-c-httphandler-webservice

Comment: I guess I need to explain it better. I already have byte array or lets say image object. now I need to show that image in ImageControl in web page. 
I could not use HttpHandler as basiacally I might have to pass entire image as querystring.

Comment: So you have a byte array on the server side, but not in the handler itself. If that's the case, then I have a solution and I'll update my answer upon your verification.