# how to convert text to image on the fly without image file

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am doing some sort of directory in ASP.NET, in which everyone has phone numbers displayed.
I dont want harvesting on my site, so instead of writing 123-123-1234 I want it to be rendered from image.

another limitation is that I dont want to save any TMP image file. I want the server to send it right back to the client for redrawing. Is that something doable? via JS?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked into canvas with HTML 5?

Comment: See (for an example): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/887985/create-png-image-with-c-sharp-httphandler-webservice

Comment: You want the server to send text that the client turns into an image?

Comment: No. I want the communication between them is via image only. but i dont want the server to create an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't do this with JavaScript. If they can scrape your page they can scrape your JavaScript code that says `var phone = '123-123-1234';`. But there are no shortages of examples on how to do this [on the web](https://www.google.com/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=dynamically%20create%20image%20from%20text). Most examples write the image directly to the client without creating an intermediary file.

Answer (score 1):

Create a generic handler that streams back an image.  Pass it an identifier that allows you to look up the phone number from your database.  You would call `Graphics.DrawString(phoneNumber, ...)` on the graphics from a new `Bitmap` and save it to the `Response.OutputStream`.

Something like this:

```
public class PhoneNumber : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var id = context.Request["id"];
        var phoneNumber = "";
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        {
            phoneNumber = DataAccessor.GetPhoneNumber(id);
        }
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
        var bmp = new Bitmap(100, 20);
        var gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        gfx.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 0, 100, 20);
        gfx.DrawString(phoneNumber, new Font("Arial", 10), Brushes.Black, 0, 0);
        bmp.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Png);
    }
    public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }
}
```

Call it like:

```
<img src="PhoneNumber.ashx?id=<%# Eval("PhoneNumberId") %>" />
```

Comment: I was just writing the same answer, but you eplained it realy nice :)