# gridview image column problem

Tags: c#, asp.net

**Work on vs05 C# asp.net .**My SQL Syntax is :****

```
if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[Images]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1)
drop table [dbo].[Images]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Images] (
    [ID] [numeric](18, 0) IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
    [ImageName] [varchar] (50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [Image] [image] NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I want to show this Images table values in a grid view.....I do it ...but the image value can not show ....asp.net syntax for gridview is

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ImageName" HeaderText="ImageName" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Image") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Image") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

i write the below code on **pageload** event.  i want **images** table values must shown when the page is load...

```
string strSQL = "Select  *  From Images";
    DataTable dt = clsDB.getDataTable(strSQL);
    this.GridView2.DataSource = dt;
    this.GridView2.DataBind();
```

Why not i get the image on my image column of the gridview.....what's the problem is how to solve?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `<%# Eval("Image") %>` syntax inside your ASP.NET server controls. I recommend you use a plain `<img>` instead. Like this: `<img src='<%# Eval("Image") %>' />`.

Check out this [this article from 4 Guys From Rolla](https://web.archive.org/web/20210510024814/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120606-1.aspx), it deals with working with images stored as blobs in a SQL Server database. Especially the section "Displaying the Binary Content" is particularly relevant to your case. Or this *very* similar SO question, [What’s the best way to display an image from a sql server database in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612342/whats-the-best-way-to-display-an-image-from-a-sql-server-database-in-asp-net)

Comment: it's does not work....or i don't get what u want to say ....do u write the full gridview tag for me...plz

Comment: Update the post with some additional links. Hope they're helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use Handlers to display images in Gridview. This is the easy and commonly used method to display image from database.

[Check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21877/dynamically-rendering-aspimage-from-blob-entry-in-asp-net)