# using rad binary image outside a databound control?

Tags: asp.net, telerik

How do I use rad binary image outside of a databound control ?

here is a link to the control :

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/radbinaryimage.html

Answer (score 2):

It's just image binary data in the DB that you want to be put into an image?

[Convert from binary data to an image control in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390983/convert-from-binarydata-to-image-control-in-asp-net)

Faithfully copied..

Create a regular HTML img element like so:

```
<img runat="server" id="image"  />
```

And in code behind do this:

```
image.src="data:image/png;base64,"+Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
```

Where imageBytes is a byte[]

You are done. The image will be displayed.

Comment: Yeah - in the same way that all images are cross browser compatible. All the Telerik control is doing is basically this but loading it from an HTTPHandler.