# HttpContext.Current.Session Is Null In Global.asax

Tags: asp.net, session-variables, global-asax

I used forms authentication.
In LdapAuthentication.cs I have property

```
public static string ReturnProject
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Session["Project"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

In global.asax.cs I trying to get Session["Project"] from LdapAuthentication.cs for check and ridirect to other pages according with rusult in Session["Project"], but I've got System.NullReferenceException. I cheked Session["Project"] in LdapAuthentication.cs - is ok

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath == "~/")
        {
            if (LdapAuthentication.ReturnProject == "Team Leader")
                HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("~/TLPage.aspx");
            else
                if (LdapAuthentication.ReturnName == "ccobserver")
                    HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("~/ScheduleReport.aspx");
                else
                    HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("~/PersonPage.aspx");
        }
    }
```

doesn't matter which handler use Application_AcquireRequestState or Application_AuthenticateRequest.

Thanks!

Comment: I doubt Session exists for that event handler. What are you trying to do? I suspect this is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), you should describe what you really want to have happen. Do you just want to redirect someone after logging in?

Comment: Plus, you need to check that `Session["Project"]` isn't null before you `ToString()` it.

Comment: I trying to get   Session["Project"]  from LdapAuthentication.cs for check and ridirect to other pages according with rusult in Session["Project"], but I've got  System.NullReferenceException.  I cheked Session["Project"] in LdapAuthentication.cs - is ok

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asp.net System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session null in global.asax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293276/asp-net-system-web-httpcontext-current-session-null-in-global-asax)

Comment: Try applying this test: if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session != null) because there it can be called more then once and the session can be null in some case. This is how it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You declared `ReturnProject` **static** property, while `HttpContext` is an **instance** property of [`HttpApplication` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.aspx), implemented in `Global.asax`.

Static property has no access to instance properties, so removing `static` modifier from `ReturnProject` should fix the problem.

**EDIT**

Now I get it, `ReturnProject` property declared in LdapAuthentication.cs, not in Global.asax.

Let me explain a bit. Every time request hits a server, new instance of `HttpApplication` (hence, `HttpContext` instance property) is created. This way you get access to `Request` and `Session` — they are bound to concrete request associated with concrete user. Related answer: [“HttpContext.Current.Session” vs Global.asax “this.Session”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/471385/55209)

What you seem trying to achieve is to pass some session variable (`Project`) to the `LdapAuthentication` class in a nice way. There are more than one way to do this, but the obvious way without looking to the source of `LdapAuthentication` class is to add `LdapAuthentication` instance field to the Global.asax, passing session variable through the constructor or property initializer. Something like this:

**LdapAuthentication.cs**

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates instance of LdapAuthentication with Project value initialized
/// </summary>
public LdapAuthentication(string project) {
    this.ReturnProject = project;
}
```

**Global.asax**

```
private LdapAuthentication auth = new LdapAuthentication(
       HttpContext.Current.Session["Project"].ToString()
);
...
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath == "~/")
        {
            if (auth.ReturnProject == "Team Leader")
                HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("~/TLPage.aspx");
            else
                if (auth.ReturnName == "ccobserver")
                    HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("~/ScheduleReport.aspx");
                else
                    HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("~/PersonPage.aspx");
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks,   but if I removing static modifier from property, I can get acces to this property in LdapAuthentication.cs  from Global.asax :    Error An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

Comment: Thanks, similar error  System.NullReferenceException    for              private LdapAuthentication auth = new LdapAuthentication(
       HttpContext.Current.Session["Project"].ToString()
);